# Unable to generate Core Data Accessor Method for managed object classes

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to code the Core Data template through Objective C instead of making the template through core data template editor itself. 
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/creating-a-coredata-model-in-code/

While working on template I am able to create core data accessor methods for those [Managed Object Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/creating_accessors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010379-CH11-SW1).
I want to know how to create this classes through code, instead of using template and then auto-creating.